# What is the top of the stack in various stack implementation?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, stack

When implementing a stack, what element is the stack's top?

- Stack implemented as a linked list
- Stack implemented as an array

Comment: last added element is top anywhere either in linked list or in array... what is ur question ?

Comment: The first question was which element array of the array contains the top of the stack? And the 2nd question is : in the linked list version  where is the stacks top?

Answer (score 0):

> Stack implemented as a linked list

In this implementation, you have a linked list, and a pointer/reference to the first element of the list. This element is also the top of the stack.

- When you want to add element, you create a new node, link it to the current head, and modify the head to be the new element. This is `push(x)` in a stack.
- When you `pop()` an element, you take the head, set the new head the following element, and return the value of the old head.

Both operations are done in constant time.

> Stack implemented as an array

When implementing a stack with an array, it is usually a circular array implementation. This means if the array is of length `n`, you refer to the element at index `0` and the one at index `n-1` as adjacent.

In this implementation, you also hold the index of the "top" of the stack, and you modify it whenever you pop or push elements to the stack. The top of the stack is not in a constant index in this implementation.